# jQuery accordion navigation with mouseover/mouseout

Tags: jquery, navigation, accordion, mouseover, mouseout

I'm trying to create an accordion navigation menu with the following properties:

Hover over a parent LI, and its sub-menu slides down. If you mouse down to hover over the sub-menu, it stays open as you'd expect.

If you move your cursor off of either the parent link or the sub-menu, the sub-menu slides up again.

I thought I was getting close - I can get the sub-menu to slideDown, but when I hover over it, I've had to mouseout on the parent LI, triggering a slideUp. I just can't figure out how to make this do what I need it to!

Here's my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

//If its a page parent (based off wordpress), add the class "display-list"
//This way the accordion will be opened up on the page you are on.
if ($('#nav li').hasClass("current_page_parent")) {
$('#nav .current_page_parent ul').addClass("display-list"); }

// Hide the submenus
$('#nav li ul').hide();
// Add a class to the parent li IF it has sub UL's
$("#nav li:has(ul)").addClass("nav-parent");
// Add a class to sub-UL if it has a parent LI
$("#nav li ul").addClass("nav-child");

// When you hover over the link in the parent LI...
$('#nav li.nav-parent').mouseover( function() {
// ...slide the sub-UL into view, and remove the 'display-list' class
$(this).children('.nav-child').slideDown(1000).removeClass("display-list");
}).mouseout( function() {
$(this).children('.nav-child').slideUp(1000);
});

});
</script>
```

And here's my HTML markup:

```
<!-- Start: Navigation -->
<ul id="nav">
<li class="hidden"><a href="#main">Skip to Content</a></li>
<li class="page_item page-item-2 current_page_item"><a href="http://www.examplewebsite.com">Home</a></li>
<li class="page_item page-item-44"><a href="http://www.examplewebsite.com/who-we-are/">Who we are</a>
    <ul>
        <li class="page_item page-item-99"><a href="http://www.examplewebsite.com/who-we-are/partners-consultants-and-alliance-partners/">Partners, Consultants and Alliance Partners</a></li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-105"><a href="http://www.examplewebsite.com/who-we-are/who-we-work-with/">Who we work with</a></li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-107"><a href="http://www.examplewebsite.com/who-we-are/coffey-graham-north-star-alliance/">Coffey Graham North Star Alliance</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="page_item page-item-47"><a href="http://www.examplewebsite.com/what-we-do/">What we do</a>
    <ul>
        <li class="page_item page-item-48"><a href="http://www.examplewebsite.com/what-we-do/technology-transactions-and-outsourcing/">Technology transactions and Outsourcing</a></li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-53"><a href="http://www.examplewebsite.com/what-we-do/dispute-resolution-and-avoidance-arbitration-mediation-and-litigation/">Dispute Resolution and Avoidance: Arbitration, Mediation and Litigation</a></li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-56"><a href="http://www.examplewebsite.com/what-we-do/company-commercial-and-private-equity-work/">Company/Commercial and Private Equity Work</a></li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-314"><a href="http://www.examplewebsite.com/what-we-do/virtual-general-counsel-service/">Virtual General Counsel Service</a></li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-117"><a href="http://www.examplewebsite.com/what-we-do/training-and-coaching/">Training and coaching</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="page_item page-item-59"><a href="http://www.examplewebsite.com/see-us-in-action/">See us in action</a>
    <ul>
        <li class="page_item page-item-152"><a href="http://www.examplewebsite.com/see-us-in-action/blog/">Blog</a></li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-154"><a href="http://www.examplewebsite.com/see-us-in-action/podcasts/">Podcasts</a></li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-150"><a href="http://www.examplewebsite.com/see-us-in-action/training-and-coaching/">Training and coaching</a></li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-160"><a href="http://www.examplewebsite.com/see-us-in-action/publications/">Publications</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="page_item page-item-69"><a href="http://www.examplewebsite.com/contact/">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
<!-- End: Navigation -->
```

I'd *really* appreciate any help, please!

Answer (score 1):

OK, thanks for anyone who looked. I've pretty much managed to sort this out now. I've replaced the jQuery block containing *mouseover* and *mouseout* with:

```
$("#nav li.nav-parent").hover(
function () { 
$(this).children('.nav-child').stop(true,true).slideDown(1000).removeClass("display-list"); // fired on mouseover
},
function () {
$(this).children('.nav-child').slideUp(1000); // fired on mouseout
}
);
```

It's a little jerky if you run the cursor back and forth over it, but it at least works. I'd like to properly stop the animation queue if possible though.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use the splendid accordion (with hover functionality) of jQuery UI: http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#hoverintent

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what all is on your page but this seemed to work with what code you supplied. It's late and not fully tested but give this a shot:

```
// When you hover over the link in the parent LI...
$('#nav li.nav-parent').mouseover( function() {
self = this;
// ...slide the sub-UL into view, and remove the 'display-list' class
$('#nav li.nav-parent').each(function(){if(self != this)$(this).children('.nav-child').slideUp(1000)});
$(this).children('.nav-child').slideDown(1000).removeClass("display-list");
});
```

Also make sure to get rid of your mouseout code

Comment: Thanks, Fadi - I hadn't spotted your reply before I added my own answer below. I'm very grateful for you taking a look at this!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but I thought I would contribute for anyone else looking for help. You really should be using the .on() event handler instead of .hover() for new versions of jQuery. Here is an example from one I am using on a site...

```
$('.leftnav-item:not(.active)').on({

    mouseenter: function() {
        $(this).find('.nav-sublock').stop(true,true).slideDown(500);
    },

    mouseleave: function() {
        $(this).find('.nav-sublock').slideUp(500);
    }

});
```